# Local evaluation of tensors

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, notation, riemannian-geometry

I want to understand why one can evaluate certain tensors locally, such as the torsion tensor in the context of Levi-Civita-Connections: $$T:\Gamma(M) \times \Gamma(M) \to \Gamma(M), (X,Y) \mapsto \nabla_X Y-\nabla_YX-[X,Y].$$ One common thing to do is to evaluate this locally in a chart $(U, \varphi)$ around some $p \in M$: $$0=T\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)=\nabla_\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}-\nabla_\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}-\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right]=\sum_k(\Gamma^k_{ij}-\Gamma^k_{ji})\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$$ which proves the commutativity of the christoffel symbols.

I wonder why this is possible and what exactly happens here. At first the torsion tensor is only defined for global vector fields. I assume that the reason one can evaluate it at local vector fields is that one extends the definition by $$T(Y_1,Y_2,...Y_r)(q):=T(\overline{Y}_1,...,\overline{Y}_r)(q),$$ where $Y_1,...,Y_r$ are local vector fields, defined on some open set $U$ and $\overline{Y_i}$ are global extensions by some bump function $f$: $\overline{Y}_i(q):=f(q)Y_i(q)$ if $q$ is in $U$ and $0$ otherwise. This would then give $$0=T\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)=\nabla_\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}-\nabla_\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}-\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right],$$ where $\nabla$ is also extended in the same fashion:
Let $X,Y$ be local vector fields on some open set $U$, then $$(\nabla_XY)(p):=(\nabla_{\overline{X}}\overline{Y})(p)$$ for extensions $\overline{X},\overline{Y}$. Now, in order to do this I would need some lemma stating that $T$ is independent of the vector field as long as it agrees locally. Can someone provide some reference to such a lemma? Furthermore I am slightly confused by the exact definition of the extensions. When choosing the bump function that extends the local vector field, lets call it $X$, do I need to choose a new one depending on the point? Meaning, do I need to choose one for $p \in M$ to evaluate $T(X)(p)$ and a different one to evaluate $T(X)(q)$? This should also apply to $\nabla$ in the same way, since I think the extensions are essentially analogous. This would mean that the case above becomes: $$T(Y_1,...,Y_r)(q):= T(\overline{Y}_1,...,\overline{Y}_r)(q),$$ where $\overline{Y}_i$ is some extension by a bump function $f_q$ depending on $q$. I would also appreciate pointing out mistakes I made in this question, if there are any, since I am self learning this. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Not an answer, but my interpretation on the nature of the lemma you are searching for: let us do it for some simple tensor-field candidate $S$, meaning it maps vector fields $X$ to smooth functions. You are looking to prove the following: if for any $p\in M$ you have that $S(X)|_p=S(Y)|_p$ for every pair of vector fields with $X|_p=Y|_p$,  then $S$ is a tensor field, meaning that there is a well defined linear map $S|_p: T_pM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

This would be the statement for 1-covariant tensors; you can easily generalize it to other tensors.

Comment: See my answer in the Phy SE [Why is the Riemann tensor $C^{\infty}$-multilinear?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/664740/203278) for this. There I discuss the RIemann curvature, but it's the same thing for any tensor field, in particular the torsion tensor field (also see the references there). The key is that $C^{\infty}(M)$-multilinearity implies that one consider things pointwise.